ArgoCD & MySQL Operator (2.1.3)
I am looking for help how to overcome that some CRDs been marked by ArgoCD constantly out of sync. I had added into the ArgoCD application this part, but no impoovement happened.
  # Ignore differences for the innodbclusters.mysql.oracle.com CRD
  ignoreDifferences:
    - group: mysql.oracle.com
      kind: InnoDBCluster
      name: innodbclusters.mysql.oracle.com
      namespace: mysql-operator
      jsonPointers:
        - /spec/endpoints/encryption
        - /spec/endpoints/type

I have this issue in two places, the static CRD "innodbclusters.mysql.oracle.com" and for backups "mysqlbackup" I noticed the same


A bit ruffer version of the ignoredifferences worked in the
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
# Ignore differences for the innodbclusters.mysql.oracle.com CRD
  ignoreDifferences:
    - group: apiextensions.k8s.io
      kind: CustomResourceDefinition
      name: innodbclusters.mysql.oracle.com
      jsonPointers:
        - /spec

